# Not reading a file?

Tags: java, netbeans, bufferedreader, filereader, filewriter

So I want to read a text file but for some strange reason it can't find the file. I have used these methods before, and I therefore have no idea why this isn't working can someone please help me out?

### EDIT:

sorry guys I left out a big piece of info which is that it can find the file when it is writing to it but not when it is reading from it. Thanks for all your guys' help and sorry for wasting your time asking a question I didn't need the answer to... Again sorry.

### Some more info:

"Assets.txt" is in both the project's root folder as well as in the src/assetregistry

"Assets.txt" will be there when the program is run

All I get is the JOption messege from the catch exception in the readFromFile() method

According to the properties of assetRegistry the working directory is

```
"C:\Users\Justin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\assetregistry\src\assetregistry"
```

***Thank you to everyone who helped, especially Chris and Andrew Thompson. The program now work and the following is the updated version. Feel free to copy it if you want. It's really a simple program.***

## Main class:

```
package assetregistry;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assetregistry {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Assetregistry();
}

assetArray aa = new assetArray();

public Assetregistry() throws IOException {
    aa.readFromFile ();
    char choice = 'Z';
    while (choice != 'X') {
        choice = menu();
        options(choice);
    }
}   

public char menu() {
    char ch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\t" + "Welcome to asset registry. Please input your choice" + "\n" + "A: Enter new asset" + "\n" + "B: Calculate depreciation and display" + "\n" + "X: Exit").toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    return ch;
}

private void options(char c) throws IOException {

    switch (c) {
        case 'A':
            aa.enterAsset();
            break;
        case 'B':
            aa.calculate();
            break;
        case 'X':
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

## Array/method class

```
package assetregistry;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class assetArray {

asset[] aArr = new asset[100];
private double year;
private double month;
private int count = 0;
Assetregistry AR;
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File userHome = new File(home);
File file = new File(userHome,"Assets.txt");

public assetArray() throws IOException {
}

public void enterAsset() throws IOException {

    int choice = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    while (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter asset name");
        double costP = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the cost price of the asset"));
        int lSpan = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of years you wish to keep the asset"));
        double mBought = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month the asset was bought (As a number)"));
        double yBought = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year the asset was bought"));
        double depr = (1.00 / lSpan * 100.00);
        aArr[count] = new asset(name, costP, lSpan, yBought, mBought, depr);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        pw.println(aArr[count].toString());
        pw.close();
        count++;
        choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, " Do you want to enter another asset?", " Enter another asset?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    }
}

public void calculate() {
    String name;
    int lSpan;
    double ybought;
    double mbought;
    double pValue;
    double Rate;
    double deprExp;
    double numYears;
    double fValue;
    double accDepr;
    String[] mnth = new String[12];
    mnth[0] = "January";
    mnth[1] = "February";
    mnth[2] = "March";
    mnth[3] = "April";
    mnth[4] = "May";
    mnth[5] = "June";
    mnth[6] = "July";
    mnth[7] = "August";
    mnth[8] = "September";
    mnth[9] = "October";
    mnth[10] = "November";
    mnth[11] = "December";

    if (count > 0) {
        year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year you wish to calculate depreciation for"));
        month = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month you wish to calculate depreciation for"));
        int m = (int) month;
        int y = (int) year;
        System.out.println("Asset regestry" + "\t" + mnth[m-1] + "  " + y);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            name = aArr[i].getName();
            lSpan = aArr[i].getLifeSpan();
            ybought = aArr[i].getyBought();
            mbought = aArr[i].getmBought();
            pValue = aArr[i].getCostP();
            Rate = aArr[i].getDeprR();
            int m2 = (int) mbought;
            int y2 = (int) ybought;
            deprExp = pValue - (pValue * ((1.00 - ((Rate))) * 1.00 / 100.00));
            numYears = (year + (month / 12.00)) - (ybought + mbought / 12.00);
            fValue = pValue * (1.00 - (((Rate) * (numYears)) / 100.00));
            if (fValue <= 0.00) {
                fValue = (int) 1;
            }
            accDepr = pValue - fValue;
            System.out.println("\n" + "Asset:  " + name);
            System.out.println("Life span:  " + lSpan + "yrs");
            System.out.println("Cost price:  " + "R" + pValue);
            System.out.println("Date acquired:  " + mnth[m2-1] + "  " + y2);
            System.out.println("Depreciatin rate (p.a.):  " + Rate + "%");
            System.out.println("Depreciation(p.a.):  R" + deprExp);
            System.out.println("Accumulated depreciation:  R" + accDepr);
            System.out.println("Current book value:  R" + fValue);
            System.out.println("_________________________________________");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no assets in memory", "NO ASSETS!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}

/**
 *
 */
public void readFromFile() {
    String line = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        line = fr.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line, "#");
            String name = stk.nextToken();
            double costP = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
            int lSpan = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
            double yBought = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
            double mBought = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
            double deprR = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
            aArr[count] = new asset(name, costP, lSpan, yBought, mBought, deprR);
            count++;
            line = fr.readLine();

        }
        fr.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is a file missing.", "FILE MISSING!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

## Assets class

```
package assetregistry;

/**
 *
 * @author Justin
 */
public class asset {

private String name;
private double costP;
private int lifeSpan;
private double yBought;
private double mBought;
private double deprR;

public asset(){
}

public asset(String name, double costP, int lifeSpan, double yBought, double mBought, double deprR) {
this.name = name;
this.costP = costP;
this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
this.yBought = yBought;
this.mBought = mBought;
this.deprR = deprR;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public double getCostP() {
return costP;
}

public void setCostP(double costP) {
this.costP = costP;
}

public int getLifeSpan() {
return lifeSpan;
}

public void setLifeSpan(int lifeSpan) {
this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
}

public double getyBought() {
return yBought;
}

public void setyBought(double yBought) {
this.yBought = yBought;
}

public double getmBought() {
return mBought;
}

public void setmBought(double mBought) {
this.mBought = mBought;
}

public double getDeprR() {
return deprR;
}

public void setDeprR(double deprR) {
this.deprR = deprR;
}

@Override
public String toString ()
{
String stg = "";
stg += name + "#" + costP + "#" + lifeSpan + "#" + yBought + "#" + mBought + "#" + deprR + "#";
return stg;
}   
}
```

Comment: Will the file exist the first time you run the program?

Comment: What a file do you read from?

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Do you want..` Better to use `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(" Do you want..`

Comment: @Tichodroma All I get is a joption message from the catch in the method "readFromFile()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
System.out.println("User home directory is: " + home);
File userHome = new File(home);
// Put files in a known and reproducible path!
File file = new File(userHome, "Assets.txt");
```

Comment: This didn't work. Am I supposed to copy this word for word, or is "user.home" an example ?

Comment: *"Am I supposed to copy this word for word,"*  Yes, except it had a case typo. and would not have compiled. Try the new version.  And of course, make sure the `Assets.txt` is in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you have put "Assets.txt" in your file system. If you are running the code from inside netbeans, then the line:

```
File file = new File("Assets.txt");
```

will be looking for the file in the root folder of your project e.g. */NetBeansProjects/INSERT_PROJECT_NAME/ (if you're not then it will be looking for the file in the same directory the application is running in).I noticed you have the line:

```
URL url = AR.getClass().getResource("/Assets.txt");
```

but you never use url in your code. Are you trying to look for the file in the same directory as your "Assetregistry" class and forgot to use url to specify the location? If this is the case then remove the "/" from the beginning of the name and construct the file like this:

```
URL url = Assetregistry.class.getResource("Assets.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Right sorry but I left out a big piece of info and that is that the only time it can't find the file is when it is reading it, but it can find it when it is writing to it.

Comment: I have opened the file and there is the info. Just to make sure that this did work I made 2 "assets.txt"s one in the project's root folder and one in "src/assetregistry" (in the project's root)